# How to get Numba to free up resources from previous kernel execution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cuda, kernel, numba

I have one kernel that need to execute twice consecutively with a different data set. When the first one ends, I call `device_results.copy_to_host(results, stream=stream)` to copy the results back.

I then copy a bunch of data into the GPU for the second kernel to execute, with calls like:

```
    stream = cuda.stream()

    largest_vals = np.full(
        100000,
        -9223372036854775808,
        dtype=np.int64)

    device_largest_vals = cuda.to_device(largest_vals, stream=stream)
```

which should fit just fine in the GPU memory (each data set fits, but both do not fit together in memory).

However, it seems that after the first kernel execution finishes copying back it's result, if I attempt to copy new data for the second kernel run, then I run into out of memory errors.

I attempted to solve this by calling

```
    stream.synchronize()
    cuda.synchronize()
```

after the first kernel execution, but no luck. Then I attempted to reset the CUDA context before each time I need to copy lots of data with:

```
    cuda.current_context().reset()
    cuda.synchronize()
```

but if I do that, then the second kernel fails to launch with:

```
numba.cuda.cudadrv.driver.CudaAPIError: [400] Call to cuLaunchKernel results in CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE
```

which seems to indicate resetting the context caused the kernel not to be executable anymore (which is strange since when I invoke it for the second run I would expect that to be setup again, but apparently it's not?)

What is the proper way to tell Numba I am done with all the data from the first kernel so I can copy new data for the second execution?

Comment: Data on the GPU is allocated like on the CPU (but with CUDA malloc instead) and need to be explicitly freed. In Python, data are garbage collected using reference counting. You can delete a variable by simply using `del`. The associated data will be deleted if there is no other reference (it would be unsafe otherwise anyway). The GPU API cannot know that data would not be used later so nothing is automatically freed by default once the kernel is executed and synchronized. Besides, AFAIK, you can reuse your array using the parameter `to` in `to_device`.

Comment: you have to [allow for deallocation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/cuda/memory.html#deallocation-behavior) of the original allocations (or else reuse the original allocations), before you can have a new set of allocations.  and resetting the cuda context is almost surely not what you want to do.  "**When the last reference to a device memory is dropped**, the underlying memory is scheduled to be deallocated..."